# insert values using select with hardcoded values

Tags: sql

I created a table:

```
create table table1 
( 
    ID NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    dist1 NUMBER(5,3),
    dist2 NUMBER(5,3),
    dist3 NUMBER(5,3)
);
```

Table2:

```
select id, name from table
```

Data:

```
ID(pk)  |   name(pk)
-------------------
  86       name1
  86       name2
  86       name3
```

Below is the query I have tried.

```
INSERT INTO table1(ID, NAME, DIST1, DIST2, DIST3) 
   SELECT distinct customer_ref, plan_name 
   FROM table2
```

for `DIST1`, `DIST2`, `DIST3` - Below values need to be inserted into `table1` along with `ID` and `name`

```
name1  0.8    0.2    0
name2  1.1    1.2    3.4
name3  4.5    4.2    5.2
```

Can any one help me how to insert values into `table1`.

Comment: What value do you want to insert at DIST1,DIST2,DIST3?

Comment: Hello, Where are you getting the DIST values from? are they in another table?

Comment: No these are the hard coded values im not using any table to get tables

Comment: forname1 i should use, 0.8,0.2,0 name2 - 1.1    1.2    3.4, name3-  4.5    4.2    5.2

Answer (score 3):

Assuing as SQL Server, if you are using MYSQL then convert Datatype as required

Create a Temp Table to Store data

```
Create table #Temptbl
(
    NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    dist1 decimal(5,3),
    dist2 decimal(5,3),
    dist3 decimal(5,3)
 )

insert into  #Temptbl values('name1',  0.8 ,   0.2,    0)
insert into  #Temptbl values('name2',  1.1,    1.2,    3.4)
insert into  #Temptbl values('name3',  4.5,    4.2,    5.2 )
```

Now, Join Temp Table and `[table]` to get data, and insert into `table1`

```
INSERT INTO table1(ID, NAME, DIST1, DIST2, DIST3) 
select [table].ID,[table].NAME,#Temptbl.dist1,#Temptbl.dist2,#Temptbl.dist3
from [table] INNER JOIN #Temptbl ON [table].NAME = #Temptbl.NAME
```

Now, Execute `select * from [table1]`, you can get the desired result

```
ID  NAME    dist1   dist2   dist3
86  name1   0.800   0.200   0.000
86  name2   1.100   1.200   3.400
86  name3   4.500   4.200   5.200
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use case statements like this:

```
CASE name
    WHEN 'john' THEN 0.8
    WHEN 'mike' THEN 1.1
    WHEN 'steve' THEN 4.5
END AS dist1
```

See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f267/1

Depending on how many names you have this could be quite cumbersome. If you have a list of names in a spreadsheet you would be better of importing your data to a table then doing a join. You could use something like MySQL's 'DATA INFILE' to do the import automatically or you could just use the workbench if this is a one time thing.